# How do I decode garbled text from the Library of Congress?

Tags: python, encoding, marc, z39.50

I am making a z39.50 search in python, but have a problem with decoding search results.

The first search result for "harry potter" is apparantly a hebrew version of the book.

How can I make this into unicode?

This is the minimal code I use to get a post:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from PyZ3950 import zoom
from PyZ3950 import zmarc

conn = zoom.Connection('z3950.loc.gov', 7090)
conn.databaseName = 'VOYAGER'

query = zoom.Query('CCL', 'ti="HARRY POTTER"')

res = conn.search(query)

print "%d hits:" % len(res)

for r in res[:1]:
   print unicode( r.data )
```

Running the script results in "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position 788: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: Any protocol without an explicit encoding is **broken**. I don't want to think less of the (to me unknown) package you are using, the "PyZ3950", so I expect it to have this encoding information somewhere! Look in the API, or failing that, in the datastream!

Comment: @kaiser.se: So very true, **IF** the data is actually the result of encoding some sensible Unicode text with a sensible codec. Sometimes so assuming is not warranted.

Answer (score 1):

```
r.data.decode('windows-1255').encode('utf-8')
```

you'll have to figure the correct encoding they used, and put that instead of 'windows-1255' (which might work, if you're right about the hebrew guess).

Comment: but hard-coding the encoding to use will fail on the next document encoded in a different but equally strange encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to reproduce your problem, but am getting into the Python equivalent of "DLL Hell". Please specify what version of each of (Python, PyZ3950, and PLY) that you are using.

You will note from the error message that there are 788 bytes of ASCII before you get a non-ASCII byte. Doesn't sound like Hebrew/Arabic/Greek/Cyrillic/etc which use non-ASCII bytes to represent the characters most often used in those languages.

Instead of `print unicode(r.data)`, do `print type(r.data), repr(r.data)` and edit your question to show the results.

**Update** I managed to get it running with the latest versions of PyZ3950 and PLY with Python 2.6 -- needed `from ply import lex` instead of `import lex` in PyZ3950/ccl.py (and likewise fixed `import yacc`.

Here are the results of dumping hit 0 and hit 200:

```
>>> print repr(res[0].data)
"01688cam  22003614a 45000010009000000050017000090080041000260350018000670350020
00085906004500105925004400150955002400194010001700218020001500235040001300250041
00130026305000180027610000270029488000540032124000330037524501270040888001620053
52460070006972600092007678800200008593000029010594900019010888800045011077000029
01152880006301181700002901244880005301273\x1e16012113\x1e20091209015332.0\x1e091
208s2008    is a          000 1 heb  \x1e  \x1fa(DLC)16012909\x1e  \x1fa(DLC)200
9664431\x1e  \x1fa0\x1fbibc\x1fcorignew\x1fd3\x1fencip\x1ff20\x1fgy-nonroman\x1e
0 \x1faacquire\x1fb1 shelf copies\x1fxpolicy default\x1e  \x1fbcd06 2009-12-08 I
BC\x1e  \x1fa  2009664431\x1e  \x1fa965511564X\x1e  \x1faDLC\x1fcDLC\x1e1 \x1fah
eb\x1fheng\x1e00\x1faPZ40.R685\x1fbH+\x1e1 \x1f6880-01\x1faRowling, J. K.\x1e1 \
x1f6100-01/(2/r&#x200f;\x1fa\x1b(2xelipb, b\x1b(B'\x1b(2i. wi.\x1b(B\x1e10\x1faH
arry Potter and ??.\x1flHebrew\x1e10\x1f6880-02\x1faHari Po\xf2ter \xf2ve-misdar
 \xb0of ha-\xf2hol ? /\x1fcG'e. \xf2Ke. Roling ; me-Anglit, Gili Bar-Hilel Samu
; iyurim, Mery Granpreh.\x1e10\x1f6245-02/(2/r&#x200f;\x1fa&#x200f;\x1b(2d`xi te
hx e........&#x200f; /\x1b(B\x1fc&#x200f;\x1b(2b\x1b(B'\x1b(2i. wi. xelipb ; n`p
bliz, bili ax\x1b(B-\x1b(2dll qne ; `iexim, nxi bx`ptxd.\x1b(B\x1e1 \x1fiTitle o
n t.p. verso:\x1faHarry Potter and the order of the phoenix ?\x1e  \x1f6880-03\x
1faTel-Aviv :\x1fbYedi\xb0ot a\xf2haronot :\x1fbSifre \xf2hemed :\x1fbSifre \xb0
Aliyat ha-gag,\x1fcc[2008]\x1e  \x1f6260-03/(2/r&#x200f;\x1fa&#x200f;\x1b(2zl\x1
b(B-\x1b(2`aia&#x200f; :\x1b(B\x1fb\x1b(2icirez `gxepez :&#x200f;\x1b(B\x1fb&#x2
00f;\x1b(2qtxi gnc :&#x200f;\x1b(B\x1fb&#x200f;\x1b(2qtxi rliiz dbb,&#x200f;\x1b
(B\x1fc&#x200f;&#x202a;[2008]&#x202c;\x1e  \x1fa887 p. :\x1fbill. ;\x1fc21 cm.\x
1e0 \x1f6880-04\x1faProzah\x1e0 \x1f6490-04/(2/r&#x200f;\x1fa&#x200f;\x1b(2txefd
\x1b(B\x1e1 \x1f6880-05\x1faBar-Hilel, Gili.\x1e1 \x1f6700-05/(2/r&#x200f;\x1fa&
#x200f;\x1b(2ax\x1b(B-\x1b(2dll qne, bili.\x1b(B\x1e1 \x1f6880-06\x1faGrandPr\xe
2e, Mary.\x1e1 \x1f6700-06/(2/r&#x200f;\x1fa&#x200f;\x1b(2bx`ptxd, nxi.\x1b(B\x1
e\x1d"
>>> print repr(res[200].data)
"01427cam  22003614a 45000010009000000050017000090080041000269060045000679250044
00112955017900156010001700335020001800352020001500370035002400385040001800409042
00140042705000220044110000280046324501160049126000760060730000200068344000350070
35040041007386500018007796500013007976500017008106500041008276000019008686000039
00887600004800926710005900974923003201033\x1e14882660\x1e20070925153312.0\x1e070
607s2007    ie       b    000 0 eng d\x1e  \x1fa7\x1fbcbc\x1fccopycat\x1fd3\x1fe
ncip\x1ff20\x1fgy-gencatlg\x1e0 \x1faacquire\x1fb2 shelf copies\x1fxpolicy defau
lt\x1e  \x1fanb05 2007-06-07 z-processor ; nb05 2007-06-07 to HLCD for processin
g;\x1falk21 2007-08-09 to sh00\x1fish21 2007/09-18 (telework)\x1fesh49 2007-09-2
0 to BCCD\x1fesh45 2007-09-25 (Revised)\x1e  \x1fa  2007390561\x1e  \x1fa9780955
492617\x1e  \x1fa0955492610\x1e  \x1fa(OCoLC)ocn129545188\x1e  \x1faVYF\x1fcVYF\
x1fdDLC\x1e  \x1falccopycat\x1e00\x1faBT1105\x1fb.H44 2007\x1e1 \x1faHederman, M
ark Patrick.\x1e10\x1faHarry Potter and the Da Vinci code :\x1fb'Thunder of a Ba
ttle fought in some other Star' /\x1fcMark Patrick Hederman.\x1e  \x1faDublin :\
x1fbDublin Centre for the Study of the Platonic Tradition,\x1fc2007.\x1e  \x1fa3
8 p. ;\x1fc21 cm.\x1e 0\x1faPlatonic Centre pamphlets ;\x1fv2\x1e  \x1faIncludes
 bibliographical references.\x1e 0\x1faChristianity.\x1e 0\x1faMystery.\x1e 0\x1
faImagination.\x1e 0\x1faPotter, Harry (Fictitious character)\x1e10\x1faRowling,
 J. K.\x1e10\x1faBrown, Dan,\x1fd1964-\x1ftDa Vinci code.\x1e10\x1faYeats, W. B.
\x1fq(William Butler),\x1fd1865-1939.\x1e2 \x1faDublin Centre for the Study of t
he Platonic Tradition.\x1e  \x1fd20070411\x1fn565079784\x1fsKennys\x1e\x1d"
```

You will notice that there are quite a few of \x1e and \x1f in the "ASCII" part before the part where it blew up. There's also a \x1d at the end of each dump. (GROUP|UNIT|RECORD) SEPARATORs, perhaps. You will also notice that the second output also looks like gobbledegook but it's not mentioning Hebrew.

Conclusion: Forget Hebrew. Forget Unicode -- that stuff is NOT the result of `sensible_unicode_text.encode("any_known_encoding")`. Z3950 reeks of punched cards and magnetic drums and tapes. If it knows about Unicode, it's not evident in that data.

Looks like you need to read the ZOOM API docs that come with PyZ3950, and that will lead you to the [ZOOM docs](http://zoom.z3950.org/api/zoom-current.html#3.4.4) ... good luck.

**Update 2**

```
>>> r0 = res[0]
>>> dir(r0)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', '__str__', '_rt', 'data', 'databaseName',
'get_field', 'get_fieldcount', 'is_surrogate_diag', 'syntax']
>>> r0.syntax
'USMARC'
>>>
```

Looks like you need to understand [MARC](http://www.loc.gov/marc/)

**Update 3** Noticed BIDI stuff like `&#x200f;&#x202a;[2008]&#x202c;` in the first dump ... so you'll end up with Unicode eventually, AFTER you drop down through the levels of the docs working out what's wrapped in what ... again, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

U need to convert Marc data for this:
U can use code below:

```
from pymarc import MARCReader
temp_list = []
for i in range(0, 2):# You can take len(res) here for all results
    temp_list.append(res[i].data)
for i in range(0, 2):# You can take len(res) here for all results
    reader = MARCReader(temp_list[i])
    for i in reader:
        print i.title(),i.author()
```